# awk script to read data from txt file

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to create an awk script to read data from a txt file and create an output script. Is it possible to create the output with awk?

`while IFS=',' read -r a b c; do echo "source "$a" and target "$b" and line "$c"" ; done < test.txt`

**test.txt**

```
"x","y","8"
"x","6"
"y","7"
```

**Output:**

```
source "x" and target "y" and line "8"
source "x" and target "6" and line 
source "y" and target "7" and line
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"source x and target y and line 8"
"source x and line 6"
"target y and line 7"
```

Comment: Input should be : "x","y","8" / "x",,"6" / ,"y","7"

Comment: To answer to this question : yes it is really easy to create ouput with awk if the input file is correct. You should try something and post your code here

Comment: Thanks Corentin & Ed. 

This is part of a script and couldn't find a way to accomplish this. 

I was also thinking to change the format of input but couldn't find any example for this

Comment: Is your input_file correct?

Comment: @User123 yes input file is correct.

Comment: input is wrong. Correct input should be like @CorentinLimier advises. When input file contains a line like `"x","6"` you will never be capable to say if `6` is the line or the target. We can just make assumptons.

Comment: How do you differentiate between source and target when one is missing?  Is there a special pattern in names?  The position doesn't provide that information.

Comment: The requirements of OP shows that the target is an optional field in the input. When an input line has 2 fields, the second field is the line number.

Comment: @user5420138 : Your code with `while` is not an awk script but a normal shell script. It is possible to get your requirements working with the while loop, but the `awk` solutions given are much simplier and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[",]+' '{print "\"source " $2 (NF>4 ? " and target " $3 : "") " and line " $(NF-1) "\""}' file
"source x and target y and line 8"
"source x and line 6"
"source y and line 7"
```

Comment: I would like to understand your code. Can you please explain " (NF>4 ? " and target " $3 : "") " ?

Comment: Its just a ternary expression, common in most algol-based programming languages (awk, c, fortran, ada, java, ruby, tlc, etc.). see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). `NF` is a builtin variable that represents the Number of Fields in the current input record.

Comment: The are two things to know about that expression.  First ( x ? y : z ) is sometimes referred to as a tertiary operator.  It's a very succinct operation that evaluates x as a Boolean expression and provides a value of y if a evaluates to true and z otherwise.  In the question you asked, NF > 4 is the 'x' expression.  NF is awk for the number of fields.   Your input would have a value of 3 for NF on the first line and 2 for the subsequent lines.  Technically speaking, your tests.txt file actually has no lines that have NF > 4 .

Comment: @Mark - s/tertiary/ternary/

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, looks like I can't edit my comment anymore, but your comments will hopefully lead folks to the correct terminology.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation. If input file has another line like x,y,z,9, script cannot read this because NF is different for this line. Can we use ternary expression for If-elif-else-fi ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Post a followup question with it's own sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

I found it difficult to discern the requirements clearly from the provided input and output.  However, if we adjust your input a bit (slightly different than Corentin's suggestion, we can provide a working awk script that provides your desired output.

Let's start with an assumption:

The input is in the following format:

```
<source>,<target>,<line>
```

Now we can write this awk script:

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN { 
  split( "source target line" , value , " " ) 
}

{
  output=""
  for ( field = 1 ; field <=  length(value) ; field++  ) 
  {
    if ( $field ) {
      output = output  ( output ? " and " : "" ) value[ field ]   " " $field
    }
  }
  print "echo " output
}' << EOF
"x","y","8"
"x",,"6"
,"y","7"
EOF
```

To be honest, the above code misses the mark a little.  Specifically, I didn't deal with the double quotes in the input or the output.  I think that the readability of the solution would be diminished if we talked about quotes.  Technically, if the quotes on the input were to protect commas (as is the case with CSV) I would consider writing this program in python (or another language) that has csv support.

Here is the output of the above program:

```
echo source "x" and target "y" and line "8"
echo source "x" and line "6"
echo target "y" and line "7"
```